# one disproportionately small item in pie chart

Tags: powerbi, pie-chart, powerbi-desktop, slicers

In PowerBI I have a column with 3 values, and the count is like:

```
A: 200,000
B: 150,000
C: 75
```

When I do stacked bar charts, I get my 3 lines, and I am even able to click on C to filter the report.
Now I have been asked to do a pie chart of the same. The C completely disappears, and I only see A and B.
Is there a way to make the C visible as a label, and to have an extremely small "radius line" I can click to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to have an extremely small "radius line" for C.  The way Power Bi has programmed the Pie Chart, they do not show very small values in the Pie Chart.  Many Power Bi power users will recommend you stay away from the Pie Chart.

To solve the problem of not being able to filter the report by C, you can turn on the Legend for your Pie Chart and A, B, and C will be listed like so:

[image]

Having C in the legend allows you to select it.  This will allow you to slice any of the other visuals on your page that might contain C data in it.  Like so:

[image]

The colors are muted for A and B in both visuals, but the C bar is still colored a darker green.

To turn on the Pie Chart Legend, look for it under the Paint Roller icon (aka Format menu) in the Visualizations Tab.